# Prefilled notes of Class attributes in Enterprise architect

Tags: class, attributes, uml, enterprise-architect

is there a way to have prefilled attributes notes in enterprise architect?

It should be something like this scenario:
1) I create new attribute
2) Enterprise architect prefill note of attribute with predefined text

Something like template for attributes.
Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this won't help directly this question.

Anyways you can achieve it through an external addin.
All you need to do is handle the [EA_OnPreNewAttribute](https://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_onprenewattribute.html) and [EA_OnPostNewAttribute](https://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_onpostnewattribute.html) broadcast events .

Comment: @muszeo only in conjunction with the above. A profile can not fill the notes field.

Comment: Ok, yes a bit of a bummer eh. I suggested tag values below but not really what they’re after.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you're after but it is possible to create an Attribute stereotype in a Profile and add to this a Tag with an initial value set to what ever you want. When you create an attribute with this stereotype, this means your predefined text would appear in a tag-value for the attribute rather than the note. Not ideal, but might work for you.

You could also have a go at writing some JavaScript to do this as well (under Scripting in EA). You'd have to use the JS to navigate the repository structure, find the attributes in question, and update their note. I don't believe you can attach a script to a UI event, so I think you'd be stuck running this post-hoc rather than having the note auto-populate on attribute creation.